# difference between しきりに or しきりと?

Tags: word-choice, particles, particle-に, particle-と, adverbs

While looking up the meaning of 頻繁{ひんぱん}, I happened to notice that one of the definitions quoted by デジタル大辞泉 states:

> **しきりに**行われること

However, there's also an entry for **しきりと** (same しきり as the first, I assume, but with particle と instead of に)

> 繰り返し何度も。ひっきりなしに。たびたび。

Both definitions sound similar--repeatedly or continually--but is there a difference in usage between using しきり**に** and しきり**と**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/95208/meaning/m0u/), the na-adjective しきり is ナリ活用:

> しきり【▽頻り】 の意味
>   ［形動］［文］**［ナリ］**《動詞「しき（頻）る」の連用形から》
>   ...

So it originally conjugates to its 連用形 (continuative form) しきり**に**, but しきり**と** is also used. 明鏡国語辞典 lists both しきりに and しきりと(redirecting to しきりに, so they have the same meaning) as 副詞. I think しきり**と** sounds a little more casual/colloquial than しきり**に**, just as the pairs 意外**に**/意外**と**, 割**に**/割**と**, やたら**に**/やたら**と**, 自然**に**/自然**と**.